# Graphic visualization library/framework for my virtual anthill

Tags: library, data-visualization, graphs, 3d

I have a great school project for my algorithms course.

I have to write a program in C that takes as input a graph that represents an anthill. One of the nodes is the entry point and another one is the exit. I have to manage an ant flow so all the ants can go from the entry to the exit as fast as possible without getting stuck.

I don't really need any help for the algorithm, but I want to build a nice graphic interface to visualize my graph. The problem is that I really have no idea how to do so.

How to place the nodes so the graph layout looks clean?
I am not required to use C for the U.I. What library/framework/language should I use?

I would appreciate any help

Comment: Please give an example of the "graph" and its properties. Is it directional? Does it have loops? Can it be flattened to 2D? etc

Comment: A very interesting project (+1). Any more info? Do you want to display the position of each ant in real-time? How many ants? Can the number be changed? How many nodes? Do you need a gratis solution, or do you have a budget? Any o/s, or cross platform? The more information you give us, the better we can help you.